# VirtualBox. How to script the start of the machine and installer run (windows)

Tags: virtualbox, vboxmanage

I can see that I can start and stop a vm with virtualBox using VBoxManage. I m not sure this is the tool I need.

I m trying to write a script that

1. Will boot the VM (different flavours of Windows)
2. Run a custom piece of software (in my case an installer) and record the results of this
3. power of the VM

I am aware of the existence of the web services and the API, however I couldnt find much online about point 2.

I would really appreciate some direction on this.
 ie should I use vboxmanage to start and stop the VMs and then run the installers in some other way? alternatively should I use the COM API, if so, any ideas of some samples on how to do step 2?

Not familiar with VirtualBox at all. But I can write code.

UPDATE: Should I be looking at Vagrant or Puppet? 
As you can probably guess this is a test suite for installers, and it would be great to be able to re use it.

Thanks

Comment: Why the minus one?

Comment: To tell you are using Windows, I had to read until I saw 'COM API'. Perhaps that has something to do with it...

Comment: The -1 is probably because you are asking about VirtualBox, a tool which is frowned upon in a server environment.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a server environment. It sounds like: `As you can probably guess this is a test suite for installers`

Comment: Hi Bart De Vos: I m all up for learning, I m trying to find a good way to test installers in the platforms I need to target. Why is VB frowned upon? oracle? Also, I d love to hear options. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start a VM with

```
VBoxManage startvm <vm>
```

and power it down with

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm> poweroff
```

although it would be better to use acpipowerbutton:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <vm> acpipowerbutton
```

You can execute commands on the Guest using

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol execute ...
```

this works fine for command line programs and you can redirect the output to your host. However, I'm not sure how well this works with GUI applications like a normal Windows MSI installer package.
Also the bit about 'recording the results' is a bit vague, does your installer write a log file that you could send to a network share before powering down the VM?

You can also take a snapshot of the VM and then look at it later

Comment: exec definetly execs tho the installer needs to be able to support running from the cmd, this is a diff problem altogether. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to script exactly what you describe. Allegedly it's possible to
do this from a Windows host environment, but in my experience, these capabilities
work fully only in Linux. (The scripting works fine in OS X too, but you can't
get RDP authentication, which makes scripting in a remote system less of an 
interesting process.)

With the addition of some various hoop-jumping, you can also update the
guest additions remotely, install/remove software, run Powershell scripts,
and use WUInstall to update Windows. It's really pretty slick.

Eric